# IntelliJ Ultimate 14 - unable to create button by using Swing form object

Tags: swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm new at this IDE and everybody says it's OK, but I can't make a step in right direction. I had a idea to make a GUI form and put there few buttons, text objects, labels... but each time I pick a object from the Swing pool it appears on form but in Component Tree window situation is different: in front of each object appears a bulb and when I press Alt+Enter or click on bulb in order to **Create field 'button1'** I get error message: *Cannot create field button1 because class javax.swing.JButton does not exist!* I tried to reinstall twice time IntelliJ U 14 but same result. Where to check that everything is correct installed, how to set it, I simply can't find myself there! I have been addicted to B4A and thought that this IDE is serious thing, smart, but now I'm not sure so. Is there some PDF like tutorial for this IDE?
Is here anybody that can help me and say an advice for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you correctly configured JDK for your project? Check File/Project structure/Project if you have project SDK defined

Comment: Hi Bohuslav, thanks for your response. I checked mentioned place, but there is so many option that simply I don't know where to "scratch" in order to make it works. I worked earlier with VS and never experienced this issue, it's hard to believe that for just settings of project a one need master degree :/ I'm very disappointed with this IDE... maybe it's state-of-art for Android development but not so user friendly as some users likes to think about it.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the JDK setting I was mentioning: http://oi62.tinypic.com/14c6wdj.jpg. Also take a look at this: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html. I understand that it can be a little frustrating to set-up if it's the first time you use it, but don't give up on it based on this initial problem. IntelliJ is really a great IDE when you get used to it. Also if the above sources don't help you in getting the project set-up, leave a comment, I'll be glad to help ...

Comment: Thanks mate, I made change according to your image; now I have been able to click a bulb there and solve error with JButton (no more red zig-zag bellow) but when I try to run, just to check what I made, in Edit configuration window is red text (at bottom of window) Error: Please select Android SDK. Probably I need somehow to add two SDK, Java nd Android in order to produce Android file and test in emulator? Thank you for your kind support :)

Comment: I'm confused. Given the fact that this post is about Swing you shouldn't need Android SDK, right? I assume that you are talking about normal Java SE application. How are you trying to run your application exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the SDK has not been properly configured.

I had the same problem and it was resolved with that, I hope I have been helpful.

You can see how to configure the SDK in intellij here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html